# java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 5

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a method in which i'm passing an Object value, and from that method i'm calling a SQL store Procedure method, the code is like this

[image]

i'm setting the value in callable statement like provided in the below code,
but their is a case, where i don't wanna pass a value in the store procedure method, after executing it's giving me following errors, any idea how to fix it, any help would be highly appreciable. thanks well in advance community.[image]

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: @SteveSmith yes i did, the problem is when i'm not passing any parameterised value it's throwing the error else, it's working fine

Comment: Debug your code. I think misReportDTO.getFilter_from() is null.

Comment: You have an if condition. If you do not pass a parameter the condition is false and you are not setting anything. You have to set all parameters at the sql call, even when they are null.

Comment: "when i'm not passing any parameterised value it's throwing the error".  I think you found your problem.

Comment: @SteveSmith but this is deliberately made, this is the case when i don't want any parameter to be passed, still my code should work

Comment: As alfcope said, you still need to set every parameter, even if you want it to be `null`.

Comment: Please post your code and the exception stacktrace as **text**, not as an image.

Comment: Looks like value of `misReportDTO.getFilter_from` is `null` due to which code is not setting its value.  As a part of debugging, you can print values of `misReportDTO` attributes before assigning them to callable statement.  Do not paste code/exception as image because it would be easier for everyone to just copy paste your code and edit it for solution.  Otherwise, no one is going to write a code snippet for you to provide solution.

Comment: I'm intentionally setting the Null value to these parameters, suppose i have to make a blind request without any parameter to be passed then in return the default value should be returned. or their would be a condition in which i'll be passing a few of the parameters but not all the parameters, still in this case the query should execute on the value of those parameters only.

Comment: No, JDBC requires that all parameters are set to a value. If you want to use default values, then you must leave them out, and you probably need to use driver specific syntax to indicate which parameters you do want to assign (maybe `{call proc(param2 = ?, param4 = ?)}`, or maybe `execute procedure proc(param2 = ?, param4  = ?)`, or something like that).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel can i achieve it using some if else conditions?